# What are the main points that must be documented for a data integration project?

Tags: documentation, talend, data-integration

I am working on a data integration project using Talend.

I have many input sources heterogeneous, I make transformations and I save output data to many output sources. Actually, I am doing Extraction, Transformation and Load (ETL).

My Talend Job is executing everyday on a linux server (the production). I have a development and test environment on a windows VM, ... In fact, I have many things I want to document and I don't really know how. I used to document web development projects (just the frontend), but not data integration projects.

Can you guys help me with some keywords, examples, templates, so that I can make a clear documentation for my client ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I hope you're using the built in database log features so you can monitor if your jobs are running successful and loading data too. If you know what failed then fixing it means one can open the job and read all the comments etc.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speak to your organizational needs, Talend is designed to be largely self documenting. If you were diligent in filling out the documentation and descriptions in your job, you can right click the job and select 'Generate Doc as HTML'.

Comment: Note: you'll need Talend version 5.0 or above to do this